# Processing OOP Issue With Classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, applet, processing

I am using Processing's Android Mode to create a sketch. For now, I only want to display an ellipse using a custom Dot class. Eclipse is not detecting any errors. I will post the entire code for reference. The main activity's code is the following:

```
package com.example.yo;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MainActivity extends PApplet  {

public Dot dot = new Dot(50,50,155,200,20);

    public void setup() {
        background(0,0,0);
        stroke(255,0,0);
        strokeWeight(10);
    }

    public void draw() {
        dot.display();
    }
}
```

The Dot class is the following:

```
package com.example.yo;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Dot extends PApplet{
    //declaration of dot's fields
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int redd;
    public int greenn;
    public int bluee;
    public Boolean through = false;

    //constructor
    Dot(int xPos, int yPos, int redness, int greenness, int blueness){
        x = xPos;
        y = yPos;

        redd = redness;
        greenn = greenness;
        bluee = blueness;
    }

    public void display(){
        noStroke();
        fill(redd,greenn,bluee);

        if (through){        
            ellipse(x, y,40,40);
        }else{
            ellipse(x, y, 30, 30);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, the app crashes instantly and the message box 'Unfortunately, Yo has stopped'. I have to admit that I cannot point you more precisely to my problem, since I have no clue as to what is wrong in the code. The Dot class is structured equivalently to the example given on the Processing help page: https://www.processing.org/reference/class.html
Both classes are within the same package.

I have tried to instantiate the dot within the setup function, outside of it, or even continuously in the draw loop, with no success.

Please let me know if you need more info. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Logs would be the place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved. For future reference:

The dot class should in no case extend PApplet, this only should be the case for main activity. However, when the dot class does not extend PApplet, Eclipse gives errors, which is not surprising, because it does not understand any of the processing commands. To solve that, The PApplet class should be declared at the beginning and then in the constructor PApplet should be passed as an argument and assigned to the variable we declared at the beginning. Now, all processing commands should be treated as methods of the parent class. This is the following code for dot (the only change I put in the MainActivity class is to call Dot with *this* as an additional argument):

```
package com.example.yo;

import processing.core.*;

class Dot{
    //declaration of dot's fields
    public float xpos;
    public float ypos;
    public int redd;
    public int greenn;
    public int bluee;
    public Boolean through = false;
    PApplet parent;

    //constructor
    Dot(PApplet p, float xPosition, float yPosition, int redness, int greenness, int blueness){
        parent = p;
        xpos = xPosition;
        ypos = yPosition;

        redd = redness;
        greenn = greenness;
        bluee = blueness;
    }
    public void display(){
        parent.noStroke();
        parent.fill(redd,greenn,bluee);

        if (through){        
            parent.ellipse(xpos, ypos, 4.0f, 4.0f);
        }else{
            parent.ellipse(xpos, ypos, 30.0f, 30.0f);
        }       
    }   
}
```

The solution to the issue is best described here:

https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

under the section *Processing in Eclipse with Multiple Classes*.